# How to sort a list/array by the second letter of each word in the array

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of names and I need to sort the array based off of the second letter of each name.

So if I have a list Names = `[ "GWashington", "AJackson", "RNixon", "BObama" ]`

How would I sort it so the array is organised by last name?

Comment: Question not clear. Do you want to sort by the second letter or by the  last name?

Comment: @sawa last name if irrelevant. Just imagine its a randomly populated string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
Names.sort_by {|name| name[1]}
#=> ["AJackson", "RNixon", "BObama", "GWashington"]
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking name.slice(1,name.length), so that it sorts by the full last name.

Comment: @ChristopheBiocca ..or just change `name[1]` above to `name[1..-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use the enumerator method `sort_by` and pass in the apropriate block. Somthing like:

```
Names.sort_by{|name| name[1]}
```